# Emacs 28 and python-mode the syntax font-lock-mode seems all off

Tags: python, font-lock

I wanted to upgrade to  emacs 28 to get f-strings support in python but the `font-lock....` seem to be all messed up.

Sometimes it works as in the past but sometimes it doesn't like why is `post_split_val_size` not orange but the line below it is. This is inconsistent across all files, so not sure what is going on but checking if it is my setup only or an emacs 28 issue (:
[image]

Comment: You should paste your code rather than just provide a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this is because font-lock does not recognize the item as being in one of its categories. You can check this by putting point on the variable and going to *Options->Customize Emacs->Specific Face*. In the minibuffer, you'll be offered the name of the face under point and the option to customize it.

However, I just checked my own python code, and it has the same issue as yours. I'm using LSP-Jedi. Are you using something like that? The text under point is `lsp-face-highlight-textual`. I guess I'll have to disconnect the server and see what that does.

EDIT: In my implementation, after getting rid of LSP & friends, the errant elements are not font-locked, they are unidentified. The properly formatted elements are `font-lock-variable-name`. This does look like a bug.